# Best Practices for using libcurl with C++

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm using `libcurl` in my project to upload and download files to a HTTP Server. To upload a file i give the `FILE*` to the `CURLOPT_READDATA` and for download `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. I have to say that the performance is not that good compared to browser download. The file size in 1.3 GB and it downloads in 2 mins in Browser Download from my local server and it takes nearly 5 mins in my curl download.

Can i get the data downloaded as `char*` in `libcurl` and write it to the file using system call directly, will that improve performance ..? Does anyone have Best Practices set for using `libcurl` with C++ , i googled for it, but found no result.  It will be nice to have Best practices set for `libcurl` C++.

Comment: I am not familiar with [tag:libcurl], but I doubt file IO is the culprit here.

Comment: Have you tried to just run `curl`?

Comment: No i didn't tried that, i don't have curl installed in my Windows.

Comment: Is there a default max-speed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706610/how-to-set-a-global-curl-ratespeed-limit